# Convert UNIX Varchar to datetime

Tags: javascript, python

I have python returning a table of 2 columns the first column is name, second column in date formatted like this: `20150716170118`. JavaScript is appending this data. I want to format the date to show something like this: `Fri,17 2015 17:01:18`.

Comment: Thanks for the link appreciate it

Comment: what?? that date looks very wrong ...`20151716170118 -> 2015-17-16 17:01:18` ? what month is that?

Comment: @omri_saadon, this "UNIX Varchar" (whatever that is) is not a Unix-style timestamp. It's just the year, month, day, hour, minute, and second all squished together.

Comment: @bgporter, that's not a duplicate at all. That question is asking about epoch-style timestamps, while this one is about an ISO 8601-style date.

Comment: thanks guys. anyone got an answer the link from bgpoter didn't work

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 -- yep, sorry. Too fast. just voted to repoen.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) and its [`strptime` and `strftime` functions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> thetime = '20150716170118'
>>> parsed_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(thetime, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
>>> formatted_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(parsed_time, '%a, %m/%d %Y %H:%M:%S')
>>> formatted_time
'Thu, 07/16 2015 17:01:18'
```

Comment: your's is an elegant solution just with std. library. Great. Didn't thought of using `strftime` again on `strptime`.

Comment: I understand all that and I used the strptime and strftime with no issues before. This time I'm querying a database and outputting the result into a webpage. Thanks for your time

Comment: Then you'll have to be more specific about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @MAM as per your question, your 2nd col. is date. **1.** So retrieve data from that column using python and the db. **2.** use the retrieved date and convert into formatted one. **3.** Then write it into your webpage (i don't know what you are using for this one). But what is the link between step 2 and step 1 and 3!? There should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import dateutil.parser as dp
dp.parse('20150716170118').strftime("%a, %m %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

You need to install [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) module for that. use `pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: I would note that this requires downloading and installing the external module `dateutil`.

Comment: oh! yes of course. `pip install dateutil` would do that. :)